Error -> "Python int too large to convert to C int"
After normalizing with X = X/255.0, displaying X data leads to error "Python int too large to convert to C int".
In Google-Colab, I'm normalizing the image array data before feeding it to model. After normalizing with X = X/255.0, displaying X data leads to error "Python int too large to convert to C int".

I even type casted into np.float32 while storing back to X. After that also printing leads to same error

Does this answer your question? "OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long" on windows but not mac

I checked that and I understand, they are storing bigger numbers than uint32. And error is clear there. But in my case, I couldn't find the root cause of the error

Removing np.set_printoptions(sys.maxsize) from the code fixed the issue :)

Any ideas on what caused this error? Looks dangerous, and without [mcve] it's impossible to understand what's going on.
